# finding independent set in a ladder rung graph

Tags: graph-theory

we find independent sets for the ladde graph and their upper bound. I was supposed to find number of independent sets in ladder graph of order n for two cases -
case 1 - p =  the independent sets contains  none of the (n,0) or (n,1)
case 2- q=  must contain (n,0) but no (n,1).

i have found p0 to be null so the number is 1.
q0  is also null set so number is 1.
i have found p1to be null so number is 1
and q2 to be {(0,1), (1,0)}
i am unsure how to find pn and qn or the recursive relation between the pn+1 and qn+1.

please tell me if i did it wrong or how to do further steps

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please define the ladder rung graph so that the problem statement is self-contained? Also you can put mathematics in latex, eg: $p_{n+1}$.

Comment: hi i have edited it to a simple ladder graph. i do not know how to use latex unfortunately